# Would a fingerprint scanner still work as you age

Tags: medical-science, biology, technology

Fingerprint scanners are known to record a portion of your finger in order to be accessed. What would happen if you age? Your hands grow and eventually even get wrinkles on your fingers. Would a fingerprint sensor still work?

For Example: A toddler is given an fingerprint scanner of some sort and he inputs his fingerprint. He ages and his hands grow with him. If he is now 7 years old would he still be able to access the  fingerprint scanner of some sort he input his fingerprint years ago or would the scanner fail to recognize his finger print

Comment: Scanners less effective in getting a clear read on elderly people http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/lose-your-fingerprints/#

Comment: Probably not as well... note however that it takes *years*/*decades* for the fingerprints to deteriorate and in decades you'll most likely change device which means you'll provide new fingerprints which include some of the deterioration.  The only places which might have issues are something like military facilities (or similar) where you may have access for decades and in that case I believe they'll probably update the fingerprints  in the database every X years for the personnel.

Comment: Sorry, this site is not for asking any question you might have - it is for (dis)proving claims. If you can find references claiming that fingerprints scanners no longer seem to work with age, [edit] them into your question.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: Fingerprint questions may be on-topic at http://security.stackexchange.com/ for example http://security.stackexchange.com/q/79882/97926